# iOS function leaking memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, posix

I am creating a client socket using POSIX socket. Since this process needs an NSArray to use the data, I wrote the following two loops to convert an unsigned char array to an NSArray and vise versa. I checked the memory situation and noticed that memory usage increases slowly when running through these functions multiple times. Can anyone spot any potential memory leaks?

```
//read code run in background
NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSUInteger i = 0;
NSNumber *aUChar = 0;
for(;;)
{
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,SOCKET_SIZE);
    if (n > 0)
    {
        [arr removeAllObjects];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            aUChar = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:buffer[i]];
            [arr addObject:aUChar];
        }
        //do sth with arr 
    }
}

//write code run in main thread when function called
int n=0;
unsigned char buffer[SOCKET_SIZE];
NSUInteger i = 0;
NSNumber *tmpnum;
NSArray *data_arr = [command.arguments objectAtIndex : 0];
for (i = 0; i < SOCKET_SIZE; i++)
{
    tmpnum = [data_arr objectAtIndex:i];
    buffer[i] = [tmpnum charValue];
}
n = write(sockfd,buffer,TCP_SOCKET_SIZE);
```

Comment: I didn't find the leak in this code, I advise you to use leak in Profile to check where the leak is.

Comment: I try Leak instrument, I saw allocation graph keep increasing while Leak do not have any thing. Is it normal or something is wrong?

Comment: In allocation, high percentage of memory is in "All anonymous VM" and "All Heap Allocations".

Comment: No leak means there isn't any instance which can't be accessed in memory. You say the allocation graph keep increasing, it means that there still are instances that you have a strong reference to it and you may never use them, so you need to find them out and release them (set its reference to nil in ARC or send release message to it in non-ARC).

Comment: Any tool could give me some hint's about which line of code is keep allocating memory?